# Не выводится форма из шорткода

Tags: wordpress

в functions.php

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_render_login', 'custom_render_login' );

function custom_render_login($atts) {
    // проверяем, если пользователь уже авторизован, то выводим соответствующее сообщение и ссылку "Выйти"
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return sprintf( "Вы уже авторизованы на сайте. <a href='%s'>Выйти</a>.", wp_logout_url() );
    }

    // присваиваем содержимое формы переменной и затем возвращаем её, выводить через echo() мы не можем, так как это шорткод
    $return = '<div class="login-form-container"><h2>Войти на сайт</h2>';

    // если возникли какие-либо ошибки, отображаем их
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['errno'] ) ) {
        $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['errno'] );

        foreach ( $error_codes as $error_code ) {
            switch ( $error_code ) {
                case 'empty_username':
                    $return .= '<p class="errno">Вы не забыли указать свой email/имя пользователя?</p>';
                    break;
                case 'empty_password':
                    $return .= '<p class="errno">Пожалуйста, введите пароль.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'invalid_username':
                    $return .= '<p class="errno">На сайте не найдено указанного пользователя.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'incorrect_password':
                    $return .= sprintf( "<p class='errno'>Неверный пароль. <a href='%s'>Забыли</a>?</p>", wp_lostpassword_url() );
                    break;
                case 'confirm':
                    $return .= '<p class="errno success">Инструкции по сбросу пароля отправлены на ваш email.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'changed':
                    $return .= '<p class="errno success">Пароль успешно изменён.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'expiredkey':
                case 'invalidkey':
                    $retun .= '<p class="errno">Недействительный ключ.</p>';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // используем wp_login_form() для вывода формы (но можете сделать это и на чистом HTML)
    $return .= wp_login_form(
        array(
            'echo' => false, // не выводим, а возвращаем
            'redirect' => home_url(), // куда редиректить пользователя после входа
        )
    );

    $return .= '<a class="forgot-password" href="' . wp_lostpassword_url() . '">Забыли пароль</a></div>';

    // и наконец возвращаем всё, что получилось
    return $return;

}
```

Создал страницу и  вывел
    do_shortcode('[custom_render_login]');

И форма не выводится почему?

Comment: echo do_shortcode(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может нужно с `echo`?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[custom_render_login]'); ?>
```

Comment: Спс о заработало

Comment: @seekAnswers ответ помог  - отметь его решенным.